# Finding length after perspective projection transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[Image of Projective transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH6LV.jpg)

Hi, I am currently studying computer graphics and not so familiar with linear algebra.

Say if I have a perspective projection matrix **M** that transform from the view frustum to the clip space **R** given the image above such that,
$$
\pmb M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{2n}{r-l}&0&\frac{l+r}{l-r}&0\\
   0&\frac{2n}{t-b}&\frac{b+t}{b-t}&0\\
   0&0&\frac{f+n}{n-f}&\frac{2fn}{f-n}\\
   0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to ask, given the length, for example, `green line in the image`, how do I calculate corresponding length before the transformation i.e. `the orange line` using the inverse of **M**.

I know I could get the length by calculate the Euclidean distance of two points before the projection transformation, but is there any alternative methods,  that directly tansform the length using the transformation matrix.
Thanks!

Comment: Map the terminal points of the line segment then compute its length in the transformed space.